# Add Document Library in my default.aspx site definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, site-definition, module

I'm currently using SharePoint 2016. I want to add a document library webpart to my site definition landing page in the . I have this in my default.aspx

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="DocumentLibZone" ID="WebPartZone1"></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

and my onet.xml currently look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Project Title="Workspace" Revision="2" ListDir="" xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <NavBars>
  </NavBars>
    <Configurations>
      <Configuration ID="-1" Name="NewWeb"></Configuration>
      <Configuration ID="0" Name="Workspace">
      <Lists/>
      <SiteFeatures>
    <!-- feature IDs -->

      </SiteFeatures>
      <WebFeatures>
    <!-- feature IDs -->
     <!-- Document Library -->
        <Feature ID="00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101" />

      </WebFeatures>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="1" Name="Workspace">
      <Lists/>
      <SiteFeatures/>
      <WebFeatures />
      <Modules />
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ID="2" Name="Workspace">
      <Lists/>
      <SiteFeatures/>
      <WebFeatures />
      <Modules />
    </Configuration>
  </Configurations>
  <Modules />
</Project>
```

Do note that the default.aspx is located in a Module called Test and my onet.xml is located in a Site Definition called WorkTest. These 2 are in the same project.

Comment: when i tried to put in <Modules><Module><File>, it throw my this error:    
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors)